# Add CSS / Code on Specific Product List Pages (catalogue) Magento

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I want to hide some things from certain product list (catalogue) pages - I know when using Wordpress you can use the page ID's etc but is there any way in Magento to target just certain product list pages?

Just to be clear, I am on about the page that lists all of the products from certain categories - not CMS pages.

In my head it makes sense that I can simply target by a URL?!? E.g. in the head if url = ...

Thought that is a complete guess.

The main aim is to hide the prices and buy buttons of products on all pages except from two categories - there might be an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Each page has a different class (classes) on the `body` element. One of the classes on the `body` element is the layout handle of the page (with `-` instead of `_`). The other classes may vary depending on the page type.
For example, a category page will have the following classes on the `body`.

1. `catalog-category-view` - derived from the layout handle
   `catalog_category_view`
2. `categorypath-{parents-url-keys-here}`. So if the category is Electronics->Cellphones this class will be `categorypath-electronics-cellphones`.
3. `category-{category-url-key-here}`. If we use the same example as above then this value will be `category-cellphones`.

In conclusion you can add some styles to what the prices for the class `catalog-category-view` and 'cancel' these styles for your specific categories using the the conventions above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within the category settings:
Magento Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Custom Design -> Custom Layout Update

This section takes XML updates, and you can add CSS to your head via XML here, like so (choose one):

```
//Simple way for CSS - Falls Back from Your Theme to Default/Base
//Goes to your theme's skin folder first

<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss"><name>css/yourStylesheet.css</name></action>
</reference>


//Specific way for CSS, can also be used for JS
//More lines, but you can change the type for different folders and javascript too

<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/yourStylesheet.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Save and refresh your cache. Make sure your stylesheets are in the right folders!

**addItem Types**
`<type>skin_css</type>` => `Magento/skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/` Folder
`<type>skin_js</type>` => Same as above, specify folder `js/yourScript.js` for name.
`<type>js</type>` => Looks in the root Magento Installation Folder. Used for the "\js\" and "\lib\" folders in the root directory of a magento install, commonly. I suppose you could tree it out to different folders if you'd like, since the base magento directory is the working directory with this type.